# How to require the user to click the Options button in a wix burn installer?

Tags: wix, installation, burn

I have a Burn Bootstrapper which has an options button which I need the user to click on before they should be able to install the software, as they need to choose from several different options for the configuration of the installation. Is there any way to disable the install button conditionally based on the UI, or if the user hasn't gone into the Options menu?

Comment: Since the user has to visit the Options menu, why don't you include the options in a dialog, forcing the user to set required options before they can proceed?

Comment: How would I go about doing this? The options are related to which packages in the bootsrapper will get run. An example would be great!